# application of integrals

Tags: integration

If $$\int f(x)\ dx = U(x)$$ then $$\int x^5\ f(x^3)\ dx =\ ?$$

I have started doing this problem by applying by parts taking $x^3$ as $t$ and then differentiating it.

Comment: hint: use the change of variables $y=x^3$, then integration by parts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea if applying by parts is good, but you need to see what is the best way to do this. I think you must take $u= x^3$ and $dv=x^2f(x^3)dx$, then $du =\int x^3 dx=3 x^2dx$  and 
$$v=\int x^2f(x^3)dx=\frac{1}{3}\int 3x^2 f(x^3)dx=\frac{1}{3}\int f(z)dz=U(z)=\frac{1}{3}U(x^3)$$

(I maked sustitution by $z=x^3$)

Now if you apply integration by parts, you get:

$$\int x^5f(x^3)dx=\int udv=uv-\int vdu=\frac{1}{3}x^3U(x^3)-\int 3x^3 (\frac{1}{3}U(x^3))dx$$
$$=\frac{1}{3}x^3U(x^3)-\int x^2 U(x^3)dx$$

This give you one form to get $\int x^5f(x^3)dx$ in terms of the function $U$ and $x$. I think you must have other hyphotesis, like what is the integral $\int U(x)dx$, because if you know that you can calculate $\int x^2U(x^3)dx$.